# How can I make the "help" file?

Tags: compiling

I just made the programm with a number of tex and cls files. The whole file compiles and give the result in pdf as you know. But can I make the help file which will not be compiled in this package? I just need this "read me"- "help" file for future users

Comment: the readme files as shown on ctan elsewhere are not usually "made" you just write them as text (readme.txt) or perhaps markdown (readme.md)

Comment: will have a try